# using sed to find and replace text from a source text file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a part of text file. with another bit of text

Source file:

```
/qwertyae
```

Destination file:

```
abc
def
efg
! unique start
/qwertyad*.$fff|$sdf|$kkr.exe|these.stay.put
! unique end
```

Basically replace /qwertyad with /qwertyae (while keeping the rest of the lines intact). Using Sed (or another method) to insert the source file specifically between ! unique start and ! unique end (and just replace the text between these 2 labels).

something like `"sed -i 's/qwertyae/qwertyad/g' file.txt"` but can use a text file source?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -i '/unique start/,/unique end/{h;n;s/qwertyad/qwertyae/}' file
```

### Script version (commented) :

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

/unique start/,/unique end/{    # match /string from/, /to another string/
        h;                      # hold in the hold buffer
        n;                      # skip to next line
        s/qwertyad/qwertyae/    # classic substitution
}                               # end of commands group
```

### Modified file :

```
abc
def
efg
! unique start
/qwertyae*.$fff|$sdf|$kkr.exe|these.stay.put
! unique end
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you,just to clarify. possible to replace the text regardless, say replace the text between ! unique start -> ! unique end. So same outcome but will insert the source file between the markers?

Comment: Added explanations